# Rails server doesn't start and there is no Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I created an empty `rails` project in windows 10 with this command:

```
rails new blog
```

and when I'm in the blog directory and running this commend:

```
rails server
```

It won't start and there is no Error
Just these 3 line in the `git-bash`

```
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 6.0.0 application starting in development
=> Run `rails server --help` for more startup options
```

There is nothing in `localhost:3000` or `localhost:8000`

Comment: https://github.com/puma/puma/issues/1797

Comment: @mrzasa I changed my `development.rb` but still have the problem

Comment: Same with Webrick?

Comment: @Kris I tried to start rails server with this command `rails server webrick` but it didn't work and like puma there isn't any Error

Comment: Try running on other port -> `rails s -b 0.0.0.0 -p 3002`

Comment: @allenbrkn Thanks but it didn't work either

Comment: does `rails console` work?

Comment: @arieljuod Yes, it works.

Answer (score 2):

```html
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :books
root 'user#index'
get 'demo/index'
get 'reminder/remind'
```

Go to routes file remove the indentation of simple match routes('i.e two spaces from the simple match routes')

eg.

Like this